# Nested for loop to do string concatenation

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to concatenate this list of URLs to get this:

> -http://example-url-1.com/chapters/**1**
> -http://example-url-1.com/chapters/**2**
> -http://example-url-1.com/chapters/**3**
> ...(all the way up to 10 [or whatever range I specify in x])

**Can anyone help me with the code because right now it's only printing the last number in the range (i.e. /10)**

```
urls = ["http://example-url-1.com","http://example-url-2.com","http://example-url-3.com"]

x = range(10)
for n in x:
  print(n)
y = str(n)

z = (str("/chapters/"))

for t in urls:
    print(t + z + y)
```

Comment: Well, what did you expect `y = str(n)` to do when it is outside the loop?

Comment: @OneCricketeer could you help modify my code? I understand the problem but drawing a blank about how to fix it. thanks

Comment: The output you've written in the question says `example-url-1.com` each time, yet you have `url-1`, `url-2`, etc in the code. So, do you want 10 chapters of only `url-1`, or 10 for each url for 30 total? In other words, you have no nested loops here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing any "nested" loop. If you assigned `y` outside the loop, then it will be the last value of the loop variable...

If you want to have "for all urls, print all chapters up to 10", then create the nesting like so

```
for u in urls:
    for x in range(11):
        print('{}/chapters/{}'.format(u, x))
```

Comment: Prefer use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) with recent version of python.

Comment: @OneCricketeer - yes that's perfect and a simple solution as well! thank you

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you expect?:

```
>>> [f"{url}/chapters/{i}" for url in urls for i in range(1, 11)]

['http://example-url-1.com/chapters/1',
 'http://example-url-1.com/chapters/2',
 'http://example-url-1.com/chapters/3',
 'http://example-url-1.com/chapters/4',
 'http://example-url-1.com/chapters/5',
 'http://example-url-1.com/chapters/6',
 'http://example-url-1.com/chapters/7',
 'http://example-url-1.com/chapters/8',
 'http://example-url-1.com/chapters/9',
 'http://example-url-1.com/chapters/10',
 'http://example-url-2.com/chapters/1',
 'http://example-url-2.com/chapters/2',
 'http://example-url-2.com/chapters/3',
 'http://example-url-2.com/chapters/4',
 'http://example-url-2.com/chapters/5',
 'http://example-url-2.com/chapters/6',
 'http://example-url-2.com/chapters/7',
 'http://example-url-2.com/chapters/8',
 'http://example-url-2.com/chapters/9',
 'http://example-url-2.com/chapters/10',
 'http://example-url-3.com/chapters/1',
 'http://example-url-3.com/chapters/2',
 'http://example-url-3.com/chapters/3',
 'http://example-url-3.com/chapters/4',
 'http://example-url-3.com/chapters/5',
 'http://example-url-3.com/chapters/6',
 'http://example-url-3.com/chapters/7',
 'http://example-url-3.com/chapters/8',
 'http://example-url-3.com/chapters/9',
 'http://example-url-3.com/chapters/10']
```